# Switch View Controller presentation from Page Sheet to Full Screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a View Controller presented as a page sheet but when something happens I want to transition this page sheet to full screen.

An example of what I'm talking about is Apple's Messages app.  If you go to start a new conversation you will see that controller is presented as a page sheet.  Once you select contact(s) and send a message you can see that controller transition to full screen.

Comment: A similar post that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539877/adaptive-uipresentationcontroller-based-on-view-size.

Comment: @Seef did you get a way to do it? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

try `viewController..modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` .

and please elaborate your question further.

Comment: What more information do you need?  modalPresentationStyle wont help because the controller has already been presented as a page sheet.  Unless there was a way to re present a controller without losing any data.